# Drop a field from elasticsearch index schema

Tags: elasticsearch

We are having a deployment of **3 node Elasticsearch cluster**. Since going into production we have about **200M documents in one index** which stores **application logs**. Sure those are just logs, but we want to get rid of a couple of **fields which are no longer used**.

But I surfed quite a lot on the web and I couldn't find much relevant things. So what are the various way to tackle this. **Reindexing** is one way that gets suggested. **But how can I add logs that are getting added in current index while reindexing is happening?** Also our cluster is **running very lean on resources**. So reindexing huge number of documents will take time and put pressure on already loaded servers.

I tried reindexing using logstash to read from one index, filter and put into another index **on our testing cluster** which comprises of just one ES server and one which runs Kibana and Logstash. We had only about **1.5M documents there**. It took almost **40 minutes**. Running that on 200M documents will be whole different can of worms. **Please suggest what can be done in such scenario.**

Comment: Why not simply stopping to include those old fields in the new documents? If you use time-based indices, your new indices will not contain those fields anymore.